# AppMaker: add role to user dynamically

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to add a role to a user dynamically ?

I understand that this is typically done at app publishing time but I'd like to have a page in the app that allows me to adds and assign roles.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. However, I'd imagine that you could set your role to a google group and then remove/add members to the particular google group through App Maker.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa It works ! Thank you very much !

Comment: which google group is this?